# meaning of 'all right'

Tags: vocabulary

> "Who? " 
>        "Well –– I don' like sayin'
>   the name if I can help it. No one does." 
>        "Why
>   not?" 
>        "Gulpin' gargoyles, Harry, people are
>   still scared. Blimey, this is difficult. See, there was this wizard
>   who went... bad. As bad as you could go. Worse. Worse than worse. His
>   name was..." 
>        Hagrid gulped, but no words came
>   out. 
>        "Could you write it down?" Harry suggested.
>   
>        "Nah –– can't spell it. All right –– Voldemort.
>   " Hagrid shuddered. "Don' make me say it again. Anyway, this –– this
>   wizard, about twenty years ago now, started lookin' fer followers. Got
>   'em, too –– some were afraid, some just wanted a bit o' his power,
>   'cause he was gettin' himself power, ***all right***. Dark days,
>   Harry. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What meaning does the 'all right' have?
OALD, adjective: [#1~5](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/all+right), EXCLAMATION: [#1~6](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/all-right_2)
Dictionary.com, [#1~7](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/all+right?s=t)
(My vibe creeps onto dictionary.com #1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OALD adj #5, Dictionary.com #4. It's used as a phrase emphasizing the speaker's certainty that Voldemort "was gettin' himself power".